# Amazon web services connection problem

Tags: linux, web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created the instance of linux on EC2. I followed the exact instructions given by Amazon web services. Created the private key to connect the instance.But my key gets always rejected. I post the question on amazon forum,but didnt get nay response. Can any one tell me the exact procedure to connect the ec2 instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setup the instance Amazon would have asked you to either create a new access key or use an existing one. When creating an access key you will be given some files which you can download. Something like access-key-name.pem as well as cert-xxxxxx.pem and pk-xxxxx.pem.

Check that your Security Group used for the instance permits SSH (port 22 by default). If you dont see an entry for SSH or port 22 then create a new rule for it.

Next click the instance in the list and scroll down to view its details. You should see something like Public DNS. Which will have a value like ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2-region.compute.amazonaws.com. You can now connect to it with `ssh -i /path/to/access-key-name.pem user@ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2-region.compute.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sure it will work. I am using windows machine to connect AWS. I am using Putty to connect AWS through SSH.is there any tips for using putty?

Comment: Yes you have to import AWS .pem keys into putty. Then specify using that key in the SSH configuration part. Just Google connect to ec2 with putty. You will find lots of links. By the way, if this answer helped then click the checkmark to the left of it

Answer (score 1):

**To use Putty this is the perfect guide from amazon :**

PuTTY does not natively support the private key format (.pem) generated by Amazon EC2. PuTTY has a tool named PuTTYgen, which can convert keys to the required PuTTY format (.ppk). You must convert your private key into this format (.ppk) before attempting to connect to your instance using PuTTY.

**Converting Your Private Key Using PuTTYgen :**

1. Start PuTTYgen (for example, from the Start menu, click All Programs > PuTTY > PuTTYgen).
2. Under Type of key to generate, select SSH-2 RSA.
3. Click Load. By default, PuTTYgen displays only files with the extension .ppk. To locate your .pem file, select the option to display files of all types.
4. Select your .pem file for the key pair that you specified when you launch your instance, and then click Open. Click OK to dismiss the confirmation dialog box.
5. Click Save private key to save the key in the format that PuTTY can use. PuTTYgen displays a warning about saving the key without a passphrase. Click Yes.
6. Specify the same name for the key that you used for the key pair (for example, my-key-pair). PuTTY automatically adds the .ppk file extension.

**To start a PuTTY session**

7. Start PuTTY
8. In the Host Name box, enter user_name@public_dns_name.
9. Under Connection type, select SSH and Port is 22.
10. In the Category pane, expand Connection, expand SSH, and then select Auth.
11. Click Browse.Select the .ppk file that you generated for your key pair, and then click Open.
12. Click Open to start the PuTTY session.If this is the first time you have connected to this instance, PuTTY displays a security alert dialog box that asks whether you trust the host you are connecting to.
13. Click Yes. A window opens and you are connected to your instance.

For an Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is ec2-user.
For a RHEL5 AMI, the user name is either root or ec2-user.
For an Ubuntu AMI, the user name is ubuntu.
For a Fedora AMI, the user name is either fedora or ec2-user.
For SUSE Linux, the user name is either root or ec2-user.
Otherwise, if ec2-user and root don't work, check with the AMI provider.

*For reference:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html*

Answer (score 0):

To use Putty you need to convert the **your_amazon.pem** key into the **putty.ppk** key:

1. Open "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\puttygen.exe"
2. Click the "Load" button
3. Select "All Files (*.*)" by default with "Putty Private Keys Files (*.ppk)" selected
4. Select the "your_amazon.pem" file
5. Click the "Save private key" button (don't forget about passphrase)